# php - Year Changed To The Current Year After Date Being Substituted

Tags: php, date

I am trying to set publish date based on user choice and give it interval in a loop. But after it is substituted with the intervals, the year changed to the current year.

Here is the sample of my code:

```
$datestart = "2012-03-06";
$datenow = date("$datestart H:i:s", current_time( 'timestamp' ));

$newpostdate1 = $datenow + strtotime("0 years 0 months 1 days 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds");
$newpostdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $newpostdate1);

echo $datenow . "   " . $newpostdate;
```

`$datenow` Will return `2012-03-06 16:19:33` while `$newpostdate` return the current date plus 1 day i.e: `2014-03-15 17:02:23`.

Why `$newpostdate` returning the current date plus next 1 day instead of `2012-04-06 16:19:33` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of `date()` is the format you want the timestamp passed as the second parameter to be displayed as. So basically you are using `date()` incorrectly.

I *think* this is what you are looking for:

```
$date = new DateTime($datestart);
$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->format(Y-m-d H:i:s);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I am new with php and haven't saw that class before.

Answer (score 3):

..because what you're doing doesn't do what you think it does.

First, you set `$datenow` to a string (not a date object), with value "2012-03-06 " + the current time (assuming that's what `current_time` returns).

Then you call `strtotime` with the value `"1 days"` (well, your string has a bunch of other zero-valued fields, but they don't change the result), which returns the current time + 24 hours as a number (the number of seconds since 1970).

Then you take that value and add it with `+` to the above string.  This causes the string to be interpreted as a number, so it turns into 2012 (and the rest of the string is ignored). So the result is a timestamp representing the current time + one day + 2,012 seconds - or one day, 33 minutes and 32 seconds from the time the code is run.  Which you then format as a string.

You could use John Conde's solution to get a more meaningful result. (I assume your real problem is different, else why not just start out by setting the string to '2012-03-07' in the first place?)